# What does prepending a file path with "..\" do?

Tags: java, filepath

I had been having a difficult time getting Java to find the file I wanted it to use until I tried prepending ".." to the front of my file path. However, I'm not sure what this does specifically. I have tried to google the info and searched this website, but no relevant results popped up.

What does prepending a file path with "..\" do?

Comment: across all platforms, `..` means "parent directory".

Comment: "goes back one directory"

Comment: Do you know what a relative file path is and what an absolute file path is? Do you understand the differences between them?

Comment: @Abra An absolute filepath is the full file path from the root of your system. A relative file path just goes to the root of the project.

Comment: Not to the "root of the project", to the working directory of the current process (which usually *is* the project root folder when working in Eclipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending `..` will mean that you are referring to the parent directory.